Aggregating Clicks per Impression Signal
I'm training a model to predict the probability of a website event occurring, based on signals about user clicks and impressions calculated across sessions.
As users interact with the website, their sessions aggregate into training data rows. For example, if user Foo visits the website over 3 sessions, we would have:

1 row of training data for the 1st session
1 row of training data for sessions 1 & 2
1 row of training data for sessions 1 & 2 & 3

For clicks / impressions (where impressions is measured in seconds), the numerator and denominator are summed across sessions, but small denominators make my signals very noisy.
For example, if in 1 session, an impression was merely 10 seconds, then 1 click would translate to a ratio of 6, which is very high.
Some improvements I've tried are:

Removing training rows with only 1 session: this is effective as most
of the noisy signals come from 1-session rows; however, many users
are 1-session only, so this throws away a significant portion of the
training set.

Flooring the denominator: e.g. numerator / max(denominator, 5); this
makes ratio signals less informative at lower levels; for example, a
ratio signal of 0.2 could now mean 1/1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, or 1/5.

Clipping the ratio outright: e.g. min(2.0, numerator / denominator);
this makes some ratio signals that are truly informative, less
informative; for example, min(2.0, 20/10) = 2.0 would be an
informative signal, but this would be equivalent to min(2.0, 4/1) =
2.0, an uninformative signal.


Note that there is not enough data to throw more features at the problem. For example, I can't just throw all the numerators and denominators into the model and hope for it to figure out the interactions themselves. I'm wondering if there are better, or more innovative, ways of handling this issue. Thanks!
